# How to import data to sonarqube database?

Tags: sonarqube

I have my own report in a custom format and I want to import it somehow to sonar database to use sonar's widgets to show it. Is it possible in general? Is there any tools to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud try to do it using the webservice api. That's the recommanded way to do it.

The supported api is self documented on your SQ instance. Here is the API of the nemo instance : http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation

Comment: Thanks @kraal, I've looked at api_documentation, where could I see an example of api using?

Comment: Until now I would tell you to use the web service client, however I just discovered now that it is deprecated: http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441873 In other words, you'll have to use the REST api directly, or write your own client on top of it once you move to 5.2. Another approach would be to write a plugin that imports your data, as Ann wrote.

Comment: If you want to give it a try: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/ws/manual-measure-ws/README.md

Comment: Yes, I see, but I can't understand how to use it directly, i.e where sould I type something like `curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:9000/api/server/system` ?

Comment: curl is a command line tool https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL it's an example, REST apis are http based, you can use any http client to call them (be it curl, a browser, apache httpcomponents https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) see REST https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer (I can't help you more, now you need to read by yourself)

Comment: Yeah, have already figured it out, and executed my first command via ws api. Thanks a lot, @kraal

Answer (score 1):

This will require a custom plugin. Not knowing what type of data you're dealing with, I'll guess that the [Generic Test Coverage](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-generic-coverage) plugin might be a good model.

Comment: The main purpose of my request is not to implement new custom plugin. We already have our own custom code analyzer engine and we just want to import data (we can produce data in different formats) to SQ database to use standard SQ widgets then.

Comment: @YegorDovganich, the purpose of the plugin would be to 
1. establish your custom metrics
2. read your analyzers reports
3. feed your metrics